# Error Executing security dump-trust-settings in Sublime Text 3

Tags: macos, sublimetext3, package-control

When I open my Sublime Text I sometimes get the following error, especially in the last week.

```
Package Control

Error executing: /usr/bin/security dump-trust-settings -d

SecTrustSettingsCopyTrustSettings: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
SecTrustSettingsCopyTrustSettings: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
Number of trusted certs = 3
Cert 0: Kaspersky Web Anti-Virus Certification Authority
   Number of trust settings : 0
Cert 1: GTE CyberTrust Global Root
Cert 2: Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority

VCS-based packages can be ignored with the "ignore_vcs_packages" setting.
```

I am wondering if this is a bug or maybe something malicious at the back? I am running OS X El Capitan.

I don't have Kaspersky Web Anti-Virus and this is really worrying me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### Edit 20/09/2016

The Package Control has now fixed and released the update with the following change log:

> ### Package Control
>
> Version 3.2 Release Notes
>        This version of Package Control focuses on bug-fixes, with notable changes   including:
>
> - OS X TLS trust roots are exported using APIs to prevent the error message
>      displayed to some El Capitan users
> - Theme, syntax and color scheme upgrades have been improved and should result
>      in fewer popup messages when filenames change
> - Various bugs related to installing dependencies have been resolved
> - Windows and OS X trust roots are exported in a way that valid/invalid purpose
>      information is now communicated to the OpenSSL-based Python ssl module
> - Further improvements have been made to handling of git/hg package upgrades
> - The Windows WinINet downloader has improved compatibility with Windows 10

This should now fixed the problem and the update should be executed automatically once you open Sublime Text.

### Edit 30/07/2016

According to the bug issue listed below the bug is fixed by the user wbond:

> Replacing the old trust list export code with new code from oscrypto.
>   There will be a new release in the near future that includes this.

That said this problem will gone away with an upcoming update.

### Regarding the bug

It looks like this is a known bug of the `Package Control` since 23rd of September.
That also appears only to OS X El Capitan (version `10.11`) users.

I guess this will be solved with an update. While this is a known bug and the cause is due to certification of the `KeyChain` there is no reason to worry about.

For more information about the bug and to keep yourself up-to-date have a look [here](https://github.com/wbond/package_control/issues/1002).

The current status of the bug is **closed**.

### How to temporarly fix the problem

Here is how to overcome the problem temporarily until the bug is fixed:

1. Open Keychain Access from your applications, (Ensure that the lock on the top-left is unlocked, by entering your password).
2. Then choose `login` from the Keychains list on your left.
3. In the search bar on the top-right, enter the keyword that is located in your error message next to `Cert 0:`, which in your case is: `Kaspersky Web Anti-Virus Certification Authority`

[image]

4. You will probably then (don't consider the above screenshot, in your case, you will have results) have the expected result underneath the table.
5. Right-click and delete the certificate. (You will probably prompt to enter your password)
6. Verify if the process was succesful by running the following command in your `Terminal.app`: `/usr/bin/security dump-trust-settings -d`
7. If the following message is shown as a result from the previous command in the `Terminal`: `SecTrustSettingsCopyCertificates: No Trust Settings were found.` then everything was successful, otherwise try again the process until you get this message.

Credits for the above temporary fix [here](https://followryan.wordpress.com/2015/11/13/sublime-text-package-control-error-executing-usrbinsecurity-dump-trust-settings-d/), and thanks to Diego Plentz user below for pointing out the tutorial reference as well.

Comment: I get this error no matter what I've done... I've spent a lot of time importing all sorts of certificates as well. Maybe its time I just stopped using package control.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way to fix it:

1. Open Keychain
2. click on your login keychain
3. Go to the search box
4. Type in the name shown in the Cert : field (in this case stuff.co)
5. Select the Certificate entry that is shown in the results
6. Right-click -> Delete “…”
7. Enter your password

Source: https://followryan.wordpress.com/2015/11/13/sublime-text-package-control-error-executing-usrbinsecurity-dump-trust-settings-d/

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with Package Control. This issue [has been fixed inside Package Control itself](https://github.com/wbond/package_control/issues/1079#issuecomment-200467370).

If you are still presented with this error then **update Package Control to its latest version**, instead of deleting the certificates *(as recommended in other answers in this thread)*.

To update Package Control re-run [its installation instructions](https://packagecontrol.io/installation).